# Can I assume that "dividing on both sides" as a step in this proof is a well-defined operation?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, irrational-numbers, number-systems

**Theorem:** Suppose $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $x \neq 0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R - Q}$. Then $xy$ is irrational.

**Proof**. We proceed by contradiction. Suppose $xy \in \mathbb{Q}$. Then $xy = \frac{a}{b}$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, b \neq 0$. By hypothesis $x$ is rational, so we can write $x = \frac{c}{d}$, $c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d \neq 0$. Then
$$y = \frac{a}{bx} = \frac{ad}{bc}$$

By closure of integer multiplication, $ad = m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $bc = n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $y = \frac{m}{n}$, so $y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

But this is a contradiction, since by hypothesis $y \in \mathbb{R - Q}$.

Then our assumption that $xy$ is rational must be false. Then $xy$ is irrational. $\square$.

**Discussion**

The proof as written hinges on the fact that $xy = \frac{a}{b} \leftrightarrow y = \frac{a}{bx}$.

It feels a bit silly to ask, but is it reasonable to assume that (given "basic facts" about the rationals and integers such that one would have at the beginning of an introductory analysis course) I can "divide/multiply both sides" to obtain this result, and also the next result that $\frac{a}{b\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{ad}{bc}$?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{R}$ is a field and $x\neq 0$ so you get all you need. Also, make sure that you point out $xy\neq 0$.

Comment: It all depends what $\frac{a}{b}$ "means". As a rational, it's really an equivalence class of pairs of integers, *not* a quotient of two integers. (you can show later that it does coincide with that). If you're developing the reals from scratch from the rationals, you're not always allowed to use what you "know" should hold. An exercise in precision (and restraint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this makes sense. When working within the rational numbers, or the real numbers, or the complex numbers, you are free to divide both sides of an equality with any non-zero number, including unknown / arbitrary non-zero numbers like $x$.

Technically, by the formal definition of fractions, your two equalities are both just different ways of writing
$$
bxy=a
$$
Since none of the fractions involved have zero in the denominator, you are in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $xy \in \Bbb Q$. We already know $0 \neq x \in \Bbb Q$ and the quotient of a rational $xy$ by a non-zero rational $x$ is rational, so $\frac{xy}{x}=y$ is rational. This is a contradiction. So $xy$ is *not* rational. This way we avoid the issue, we just use that rationals are closed under division.

Comment: I don't think we avoid the issue. We just hide it away by not explicitly writing the rational number $xy$ as an integer fraction.

Comment: @Arthur He's already assuming a rational is a quotient of two numbers. We don't know what stage he's at in developing the reals vs rationals etc. so it's hard to say what the correct answer in this case is. What is the OP allowed to use? And "$x=y$ implies $f(x)=f(y)$" is the definition of a function or the application of a logical axiom? We don't know what the OP's frame of reference is.